# jQuery sort array based on number after last comma

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Suppose I have an array:

```
["Team A, 6, 2, 12","Team B, 7, 1, 14","Team C, 4, 4, 8"]
```

How could I sort the array such that the last numbers in each array element are in descending order? That is:

```
["Team B, 7, 1, 14","Team A, 6, 2, 12","Team C, 4, 4, 8"]
```

I have checked out various `compare functions`, but I cannot figure out how to tailor them to this specific situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regex to get last digits in each string in `Array#sort()`

```js
let reg = /\d+$/;

let arr = ["Team A, 6, 2, 12","Team B, 7, 1, 14","Team C, 4, 4, 8"];
arr.sort((a, b) => reg.exec(b) - reg.exec(a));

console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to define your own compare function

```js
var arr = ["Team A, 6, 2, 12","Team B, 7, 1, 14","Team C, 4, 4, 8"];
function compare(a,b){
  var vala = a.split(',').pop();
  var valb = b.split(',').pop();
  return valb-vala;
}
arr.sort(compare);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: No need for parseInt(). Using **`-`** on 2 numeric strings casts each to number automatically

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl, I knew one thing from you

Comment: Or `return b.split(',').pop() - a.split(',').pop()` if you wanted a one-liner.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, all you need to do is extract that last number, then use it in your comparason:

```js
var myArray = ["Team A, 6, 2, 12","Team B, 7, 1, 14","Team C, 4, 4, 8"];

function sorter(item1, item2) {
    const split1 = item1.split(",");
    const split2 = item2.split(",");
    
    const num1 = split1[split1.length - 1] || 0;
    const num2 = split2[split2.length - 1] || 0;

    return num2 - num1; 
}

myArray.sort(sorter)
console.log(myArray)
```

Comment: or `myArray.sort((item1, item2) => Number(item2.split(",").pop()) - Number(item1.split(",").pop()));`

Comment: You can omit the `Number()` calls, because the `-` operator coerces both operands to numbers automatically.